# Can a PHP generated main page be indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, php, html

I generate an index.html file in a PHP script to avoid PHP code within HTML and to show content that is delivered by another script hourly. (Like next flights within an hour.)

This script overwrites the file each time the content is ready (I plan to do this with a cron job).

Then, will my *index.html* be indexed by Google or it will be punished for being generated content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google won't care whether the *index.html* file is created dynamically or created every hour. What is important is the content of the file.

For example, this is what Google says about [scraped content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312?hl=en&ref_topic=2371375).

> Some webmasters use content taken (“scraped”) from other, more
>   reputable sites on the assumption that increasing the volume of pages
>   on their site is a good long-term strategy regardless of the relevance
>   or uniqueness of that content. Purely scraped content, even from
>   high-quality sources, may not provide any added value to your users
>   without additional useful services or content provided by your site;

You just need to make sure you follow their [webmaster guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769#2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was worried that somehow, it could be targeted as the 'generated content' punishment.